# Algebrizing analytic quotients of algebraic spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, gaga

Suppose that $Y$ is an algebraic space over $\mathbb{C}$ which is "nice" (say, separated and of finite type). Let $R\subset Y\times Y$ be a closed algebraic subspace which forms a categorical equivalence relation. Now, suppose that the quotient of $Y$ by $R$ makes sense in the analytic category. That is,
there is a complex analytic space $Z^{an}$ and a map $f:Y^{an}\rightarrow Z^{an}$ such that

1. $f$ is the categorical quotient of $Y^{an}$ by $R^{an}$,
2. The complex points of $Z^{an}$ parametrize the $R^{an}$-equivalence classes of $Y^{an}$, and
3. The sheaf $O_{Z^{an}}$ coincides with the subsheaf of elements of $f_*O_{Y^{an}}$ that have the same pullback along the two projections $\pi_i:R^{an}\to Y^{an}$. (This can be ignored if we assumed $Y,R$ are reduced)

Does it follows that there is a categorical quotient $Z$ of $Y$ by $R$ in the category of algebraic spaces, whose analytification is $Z^{an}$?

I'd also greatly appreciate any references to "GAGA" results of this type. Thanks!

Comment: Is your categorical quotient $f$ a *uniform* categorical quotient?  If so, then $f$ is flat over a dense open subset of $Z^{\text{an}}$.  This implies that $\pi_1:R\to Y$ is flat over a dense open subset of $Y$.  Then you can play the "usual game":  choose $i:Y\hookrightarrow \overline{Y}$, a Nagata compactification; form the closure $\overline{R}$ of $R$ in $Y\times \overline{Y}$; this is flat over a dense open $U$ of $Y$; use this to embed a dense open subset of $Z^{\text{an}}$ as a locally closed subspace of the Hilbert algebraic space of $\overline{Y}$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Why can't one take the quotient in the category of algebraic stacks? Call this $\mathcal{Z}$. By the "niceness" assumptions this should be a finitely presented algebraic stack. now, by assumption,  $\mathcal{Z}^{an}$ is a complex analytic space. Thus, the inertia groups are trivial of $\mathcal{Z}^{an}$  hence $\mathcal{Z}$ are trivial. Thus, $\mathcal{Z}$ is an algebraic space. Where does this line of reasoning go wrong?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar.  That might work.  However, the OP did not state that $R$ is flat over (all of) $Y$.  So it is not immediately clear how to form an fppf stack out of $Y$ and $R$.  My comment is that, if there is a "good" quotient in the category of analytic spaces, then that good quotient is bimeromorphic to a subspace of the Hilbert algebraic space of any Nagata compactification.  It should be possible to use this to prove that the quotient is an algebraic space.

Comment: @JasonStarr, I'm not familiar with the notion of uniform categorical quotients. But I don't know how to proceed once one gets a dense open subset of Z^{an} is, say, even an affine scheme. In the case I'm thinking about, thats actually easy to see.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar, your argument sounds interesting but can you quotient out by an arbitrary equivalence relation? I can't find results of this type. I'm also unsure about the rest of your argument, but I'd be interested to hear more!

Comment: @jacob.  Since you clearly have additional hypotheses you are willing to impose, I suggest you tell us what they are.  Anyway, the "usual game" goes as follows: for the dense open subscheme U of Y, form the morphism $g:U\to \text{Hilb}_{\overline{Y}}$.  Now define $\widetilde{Y}$ to be the closure of the graph of $U$ in the product $\overline{Y}\times \text{Hilb}_{\overline{Y}}$.  The first projection, $p_1:\widetilde{Y}\to \overline{Y}$ is proper and birational.  The image of the second projection, $p_2:\widetilde{Y}\to \widetilde{Z}$, is a proper algebraic space bimeromorphic to $Z$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Ok,  you're right. If the equivalence relation is flat, then my argument should work.

Comment: @jacob Assuming (like in Jason's comment) that your equivalence relation is fppf, then $\mathcal{Z}$ (as defined in my comment above) will be a finitely presented algebraic stack....

Comment: By assumption, its analytification is a complex analytic space and thus has trivial inertia groups. If $z$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-object of $\mathcal{Z}$ with non-trivial inertia group, then the corresponding object of $\mathcal{Z}^{an}$ has a non-trivial inertia group. Thus, as $\mathcal{Z}^{an}$ is a complex analytic space, the inertia groups of all $\mathbb{C}$-objects of $\mathcal{Z}$ are trivial. Since $\mathcal{Z}$ is a finitely presented algebraic stack over $\mathbb{C}$ such that...

Comment: every $\mathbb{C}$-object has a trivial inertia group, we may conclude that $\mathcal{Z}$ is an algebraic space by Corollary 2.2.7 of http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/kmpaper.pdf

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar It occurs to me your argument might have an issue.. youre first taking the quotient in algebraic stack world. Then you wanna say that the corresponding analytification is a complex analytic space. However, thats no necessarily true. The quotient in  the category of complex analytic spaces might NOT be the quotient in the category of complex analytic stacks (or whatever the right notion is). In fact, if you have a quotient in algebraic stack world, you can maybe always get the quotient in algebraic space world by taking the coarse space or something...?

Comment: @jacob Ow, I see. The issue is that, if $q:X\to \mathcal{X}$ is an (fppf) "quotient map" in the category of finitely presented algebraic stacks over $\mathbb{C}$, then the analytification $q^{an}:X^{an}\to \mathcal{X}^{an}$ might not be a "quotient map" in the category of complex analytic stacks. That's what you're saying right?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Hmm.. I don't think thats what I was saying, though I guess that could also be an issue. I was more saying that if $q:X^{an}\rightarrow \mathcal{X}^{an}$ is an fppf quotient map in the category of complex analytic spaces, it might not be a quotient map in the category of complex analytic stacks.

Comment: @jacob I see... My line of reasoning was that the analytification of the associated algebraic stack has trivial inertia groups, because 1) the analytification of the associated algebraic stack IS the quotient in the category of complex analytic stacks and 2) the latter quotient coincides with the quotient in the category of complex analytic spaces. Although I think 1) and 2) might actually be true, I do agree that it's not clear.